# what should I do with overgrown beautiful clusters of Chia seed leaves?

Tags: salad

A few weeks ago I soaked Chia Seeds to add to my daily smoothie the following morning.However, this got forgotten to add and left over for the next day. Instead of throwing away in the trash bin, I threw these soaked and smelly in my back vegetable plot. Tiny leaves have started to sprout. Can I eat them?

Comment: funny, someone was just asking about chia leaves a couple days ago here    .....                                                                                                  http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/58703/can-i-eat-chia-leaves      ............                                                                                                    A very interesting discussion ensued with plenty of references & info.  Check it out if this link (above) comes through in a usable way.

Comment: Re. the close vote: I feel chia leaves as food item are uncommon enough to warrant leaving this question open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add them to a salad and they are great in tea.